# Why does java linkedlist implementation use the interface deque?

Tags: java, deque, linked-list

I was looking at the java implementation of LinkedList, and found this:

```
public class LinkedList<E> 
       extends AbstractSequentialList<E> implements List<E>,
               Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable
```

Why should a LinkedList support the Deque interface? 
I understand the desire to add elements to the end of the linked list, but those methods should have been incuded in the List interface.

Comment: Just because you can implement a queue with a linkedlist?

Comment: Not all Lists are Deques and not all Deques are Lists.

Comment: I now understand that the list interface cannot be changed just because one of the implementations happens to be a linked list, and linked list can easily accommodate the deque operations. I probably would have defined a linkedlist interface which extends the list interface and the deque interface. And then defined a linkedlistImpl class. So, I guess "The LinkedList implementation happens to to satisfy the Deque contract, so why not make it implement the interface?" response by Qwerky is appropriate. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `LinkedList` implementation happens to to satisfy the `Deque` contract, so why not make it implement the interface?

Answer (score 4):

As the JavaDocs states:

These operations allow linked lists to be used as a stack, queue, or **double-ended queue.**

The List interface is just a List i.e. you can add or remove.  So a basic implementation of the List interface has to just provide those simple methods e.g. ArrayList.  The Deque interface is the double ended Queue and iava's LinkedList IS-A Double Ended Queue.

Answer (score 4):

IIRC, `deque` stands for `double end queue`. In the case you mention, it's not logical to define a generic `List` as a deque. For instance, an `ArrayList` is not designed for the `Deque` interface. Insertions will be efficient in the end of the list, but absolutely not at its beginning (because it will cause the re-allocation of a whole array, I think).

The `LinkedList` is, on the other end, perfectly designed for the `Deque` interface, as it is a double linked list.

Answer (score 1):

Because a double-ended queue might be implemented using something other than a `LinkedList` and one's code may depend on anything with such functionality, so the `Deque` interface needs to be available separately.

`List` should not itself implement/extend `Deque` because adding to/removing from the start of a list may not be something that can be (easily) supported by every implementation.